# LOG: connection failed during start up processing: user= database= FATAL: GSSAPI authentication failed for user "postgres"

Tags: postgresql, enterprisedb

I am trying to configure Kerberos for GSSAPI Currently I have two nodes
One the KDC server (windows server 2016) and the the other is Postgres-server(Ubuntu).
I have created Active directory on in kdc-server and create user with the name of
postgres and selected the option  "password will never expire".

Then I have installed a kerbrose client of MIT.
here is krb5.ini on kdc server.

```
[libdefaults]
    default_realm = HIGHGO.CA

# The following krb5.conf variables are only for MIT Kerberos.
    kdc_timesync = 1
    ccache_type = 4
    forwardable = true
    proxiable = true

# The following encryption type specification will be used by MIT Kerberos
# if uncommented.  In general, the defaults in the MIT Kerberos code are
# correct and overriding these specifications only serves to disable new
# encryption types as they are added, creating interoperability problems.
#
# The only time when you might need to uncomment these lines and change
# the enctypes is if you have local software that will break on ticket
# caches containing ticket encryption types it doesn't know about (such as
# old versions of Sun Java).

#   default_tgs_enctypes = des3-hmac-sha1
#   default_tkt_enctypes = des3-hmac-sha1
#   permitted_enctypes = des3-hmac-sha1

# The following libdefaults parameters are only for Heimdal Kerberos.
    fcc-mit-ticketflags = true

[realms]
    HIGHGO.CA = {
        kdc = kdc.highgo.ca
        admin_server = kdc.highgo.ca
    }
    ATHENA.MIT.EDU = {
        kdc = kerberos.mit.edu
        kdc = kerberos-1.mit.edu
        kdc = kerberos-2.mit.edu:88
        admin_server = kerberos.mit.edu
        default_domain = mit.edu
    }
    ZONE.MIT.EDU = {
        kdc = casio.mit.edu
        kdc = seiko.mit.edu
        admin_server = casio.mit.edu
    }
    CSAIL.MIT.EDU = {
        admin_server = kerberos.csail.mit.edu
        default_domain = csail.mit.edu
    }
    IHTFP.ORG = {
        kdc = kerberos.ihtfp.org
        admin_server = kerberos.ihtfp.org
    }
    1TS.ORG = {
        kdc = kerberos.1ts.org
        admin_server = kerberos.1ts.org
    }
    ANDREW.CMU.EDU = {
        admin_server = kerberos.andrew.cmu.edu
        default_domain = andrew.cmu.edu
    }
        CS.CMU.EDU = {
                kdc = kerberos-1.srv.cs.cmu.edu
                kdc = kerberos-2.srv.cs.cmu.edu
                kdc = kerberos-3.srv.cs.cmu.edu
                admin_server = kerberos.cs.cmu.edu
        }
    DEMENTIA.ORG = {
        kdc = kerberos.dementix.org
        kdc = kerberos2.dementix.org
        admin_server = kerberos.dementix.org
    }
    stanford.edu = {
        kdc = krb5auth1.stanford.edu
        kdc = krb5auth2.stanford.edu
        kdc = krb5auth3.stanford.edu
        master_kdc = krb5auth1.stanford.edu
        admin_server = krb5-admin.stanford.edu
        default_domain = stanford.edu
    }
        UTORONTO.CA = {
                kdc = kerberos1.utoronto.ca
                kdc = kerberos2.utoronto.ca
                kdc = kerberos3.utoronto.ca
                admin_server = kerberos1.utoronto.ca
                default_domain = utoronto.ca
    }

[domain_realm]
    .mit.edu = ATHENA.MIT.EDU
    mit.edu = ATHENA.MIT.EDU
    .media.mit.edu = MEDIA-LAB.MIT.EDU
    media.mit.edu = MEDIA-LAB.MIT.EDU
    .csail.mit.edu = CSAIL.MIT.EDU
    csail.mit.edu = CSAIL.MIT.EDU
    .whoi.edu = ATHENA.MIT.EDU
    whoi.edu = ATHENA.MIT.EDU
    .stanford.edu = stanford.edu
    .slac.stanford.edu = SLAC.STANFORD.EDU
        .toronto.edu = UTORONTO.CA
        .utoronto.ca = UTORONTO.CA
```

created principle

```
setspn -A postgres/pg.highgo.ca@HIGHGO.CA postgres
```

after creating principle I have tested it with the following command

```
c:\Users\administrator\Desktop>kinit postgres
Password for postgres@HIGHGO.CA:
```

which is working fine.

that's how I have created key tab

```
ktpass -out pgkt.keytab -princ postgres/pg.highgo.ca@HIGHGI.CA
-mapUser enterprisedb -pass Casper@12 -crypto all -ptype KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL
```

and cpoy this file in postgres server
and replace it with the file /etc/krb5.keytab with following permission.

```
chmod 600 /etc/krb5.keytab
```

and here is my /etc/host entries on linux and windows.

```
192.168.100.112 pg.highgo.ca
192.168.100.114 kdc.highgo.ca
```

and I have put an entery in postgress.conf.

```
krb_server_keyfile = '/etc/krb5.keytab'
```

and here is pg_hba.conf entries.

```
 host     all             all              0.0.0.0/0               gss include_realm=0
```

after that I have tried to access postgress server with the following command .

```
psql -U postgres -d postgress -h 192.168.100.114
```

in responce I got the following error on windows.

```
psql: error: could not connect to server: SSPI continuation error: The specified target is unknown or unreachable
 (80090303)
```

and seen the logs on posgtes.

```
2020-08-18 05:49:36.534 PDT [5086] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  connection failed during start up processing: user= database=
2020-08-18 05:49:36.541 PDT [5087] postgres@postgres FATAL:  GSSAPI authentication failed for user "postgress"
2020-08-18 05:49:36.541 PDT [5087] postgres@postgres DETAIL:  Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 97: "host     all             all              0.0.0.0/0               gss include_realm=0 "
```

I have checked the lots of tutorials but did not get a chance to resolve it.

> (Note : same commands works fine with MD5 authentication )

thanks advance.

Comment: would you mind editing your post for accuracy?  I see some instances where you spell `postgres` as `postgress`, and I'm not sure if the database is complaining about your spelling or actually failing to authenticate.  I also see `HIGHGO` spelled as `HIGHGI`

Comment: I have edit  the post thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolve it with the help of my Colleagues this is done on the fresh environment.
Steps:

> (Note : there no need of kerbrose client on the PG-Server machien (mine is Ubuntu 18.xx))

1. Active Directory is setup on Windows 2016 MYDOMAIN.CA and
   EPAS Server 11 or 12 is installed on both machines.
   [Active Directory Setup Link](http://pc-addicts.com/setup-active-directory-server-2016/)
2. Make sure time zone and time on both machines are the same.

- /etc/hosts
- IP of Windows machine is 192.168.100.19 and that of Linux is
  192.168.100.17.

  Also assuming that Windows machine name is “client” so its full name
  is “client.mydomain.ca”.

  Enter the following in /etc/hosts on linux (Comment out other
  entries)

> ```
> 192.168.100.19 client.mydomain.ca client
> 192.168.100.17 pg.mydomain.ca  pg
> ```

- Enter the following in c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts on
  Windows

> ```
> 192.168.100.19 client.mydomain.ca
> 192.168.100.17 pg.mydomain.ca
> ```

Verify the host are communicating with the ping.

**Create User in Active Directory (Windows Machine)**

- Assuming you are logged in as Administrator, In “Server Manager”
  click “Tools” and select “Active Directory Users and Computers”
- Under your domain “MYDOMAIN.CA” select users to show all users

  Right Click Administrator and select “Copy”
- Enter “pguser” in “First Name” and “User logon name” fields.
  Click Next. Domain “MYDOMAIN.CA” should be shown in combo box against
  “User logon name”
- Enter password for user and uncheck “Password never expires”
  checkbox. ->  Click Next -> Click Finish. User account is created.
- Double click this user in Users list OR right click this user and
  select Properties.
- In Account Tab, under Account options check “This account supports
  kerberos AES 256 bit encryption” checkbox and click OK.
- Log off Windows and login using “pguser” user.

**Create Keytab**

- Windows Machine: Open Command Prompt as Administrator and enter the
  following command to create Keytab.

> ```
>   ktpass -out krb5.keytab -mapUser pguser@MYDOMAIN.CA +rndPass -mapOp set +DumpSalt -crypto AES256-SHA1 -ptype KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL -princ POSTGRES/pg.mydomain.ca@MYDOMAIN.CA
> ```

- Note that this command should not give any error or warning. If you
  see an error or warning and the keytab is generated, this keytab will
  not work.
- If the keytab is created successfully, you can check by opening
  pguser user properties, Account tab that “user logon name” is
  changed to postgres/pg.mydomain.ca.
- Now you have created keytab file “krb5.keytab”.
- Linux Machine: Copy this file to Linux machine as “/etc/krb5.keytab”.

> //Suppose file is on Desktop of user edb on Linux machine. su to
> become root.

> cd /etc/

> cp /home/edb/Desktop/krb5.keytab .

> chown enterprisedb:enterprisedb krb5.keytab

> chmod 600 krb5.keytab

- Open postgresql.conf file and set krb_server_keyfile to
  “/etc/krb5.keytab” (uncomment this line as it is commented out by
  default)

> krb_server_keyfile = '/etc/krb5.keytab'

- Open pg_hba.conf file and add the following line (Comment out all
  other lines except “local all enterprisedb trust/md5” so any remote
  user can only connect using gss)

> local all enterprisedb             trust

> host all  all        0.0.0.0/0   gss

- Restart server.
- Create user “pguser@MYDOMAIN.CA”.

> CREATE USER "pg1postgres@HIGHGO.CA" SUPERUSER CREATEDB CREATEROLE;

**PSQL command from Windows**

Issue this command to connect to D on Linux

> psql -U pgUSER@MYDOMAIN.CA -d edb -h pg.mydomain.ca

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue experienced in earlier releases of Postgres and EDB Postgres v. 12, since GSSAPI encryption has been added, but a bug existed.  The bug has been fixed in commit `79e594cf04754d55196d2ce54fc869ccad5fa9c3`, released in v. 12.3.  If you can upgrade to v. 12.3, you may be able to work around this issue.

If you require use of an older client for some reason, please be sure to set `gssencmode=disable` in your connection string or set `PGGSSAPIENCMODE=disable` in your environment.

Comment: you are talking about the Postgres 12.3 or  EDB Postgres 12.3, I am asking it because I am already using EDB Postgres 12.3 in my Linux VM.

Comment: And also there one more thing, I have tried authentication with GSSAPI while my KDC server was linux (Ubuntu 18.xx) in that case I got connected
successfully. But I am not able to auth with the GSSAPI in case of Active Directory KDC. and also the version of the EDB Postgres is same 12.xx.